# How to use an aggregation function in subquery scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe where I am aggregating the difference in two dates "max(openday) and openday" in a subquery in the query.
I need to add a new column of the difference between max(opday) and opday to a_table
How can i do it?

I tried to use:

```
a_table.alias("a").join(b_table.alias("b"), $"a.name == "b.name", "left")
 .withColumn("difference", 
    when(condition, datediff(a.agg(max("opday").alias("max"))("max"), $"opday"))

val a_table = Seq(
    ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-07-22"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
    ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-05-01"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
    ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-05"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
    ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-03-04"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
    ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-02-12"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0)
).toDF("name", "openday", "current_date", "salary")

val b_table = Seq(
        ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
        ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-02"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
        ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-03"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
        ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-07"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0),
        ("James", Date.valueOf("2021-01-08"), Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"), 600.0)
).toDF("name", "openday", "current_date", "salary")
```

Comment: what is the required output

Answer (score 0):

since i could not Join because the name column would be ambiguous, i just performed union with the two dataframes

```
val result_table = joined_table.groupBy("name").agg(max("openday").as("max_open_day"))
      .withColumnRenamed("name","name_max")
      .join(joined_table,col("name_max") === joined_table("name"),"inner").drop("name_max")
      .withColumn("diff",datediff(col("max_open_day"),col("openday"))).drop("max_open_day")

    result_table.show
```

this is the result that i got.

```
+-----+----------+------------+------+----+
| name|   openday|current_date|salary|diff|
+-----+----------+------------+------+----+
|James|2021-07-22|  2021-01-01| 600.0|   0|
|James|2021-05-01|  2021-01-01| 600.0|  82|
|James|2021-01-05|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 198|
|James|2021-03-04|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 140|
|James|2021-02-12|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 160|
|James|2021-01-01|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 202|
|James|2021-01-02|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 201|
|James|2021-01-03|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 200|
|James|2021-01-07|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 196|
|James|2021-01-08|  2021-01-01| 600.0| 195|
+-----+----------+------------+------+----+
```

Was this what you were expecting?

Comment: Not really the answer being sought.